# Convert Large Number of labels to annotations in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I have Parcels counting to approximately 35000 for which I want to create feature linked annotations. But when I am ready with all the symbol and labelling properties and right click the layer to "convert labels to Annotations" after converting about 5000 records, ArcGIS crashes, I have tried it several time but no luck. If someone has go through this issues and have a solution, please let me know it will be a great help.